# Free cache memory

Tags: cache, ram

[image: System Monitor]

Hi. I'm trying to free cache memory in Ubuntu. I searched several tutorials (including install `bleachbit`) and none of these helped me. Does anyone know how to free this cache?

Comment: Have you read: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ?

Comment: This is unnecessary (and of no benefit) in Linux. Now, about your XY Problem: What are really trying to accomplish?